# Django Rest Framework implementing many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want implement a `many to many` relationship such that one person can join multiple social clubs and one social club can have multiple members. This is how far I've got but this doesn't display the movie details and serialization gives me an error -
`Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'club_name'.`

`models.py`

```
class Club(models.Model):
  club_name = models.CharField(default='',blank=False,max_length=100)

class Person(models.Model):
  person_name = models.CharField(default='',blank=False,max_length=200)
  clubs = models.ManyToManyField(Club)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Club
    fields = ('url','id','club_name','person')

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  clubs = ClubSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ('url','id','person_name','clubs')
```

`views.py`

```
class ClubDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
serializer_class = ClubSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    club = Clubs.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk',None))
    persons = Person.objects.filter(club=club)
    return persons

class ClubList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Club.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ClubSerializer


class PersonDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  serializer_class = PersonSerializer


def get_object(self):
  person_id = self.kwargs.get('pk',None)
  return Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
url(r'^$', views.api_root),
url(r'^clubs/$',
views.ClubList.as_view(),
name='club-list'),
url(r'^clubs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/persons/$',
views.ClubDetail.as_view(),
name='club-detail'),
url(r'^person/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
views.PersonDetail.as_view(),
name='person-detail'),
])
```

on my local server, I get the clubs list which navigates me to clubdetail view,but it doesn't show the movie names or, but I can't see the person list. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your code here. Namely:

- ClubSerializer.Meta.fields - person should be person_set
- PersonSerializer - clubs should be `clubs = ClubSerializer(many=True)`
- ClubDetail.serializer_class  - ClubSerializer should be PersonSerializer
- ClubDetail - queryset should be `persons = Person.objects.filter(clubs=club)`

If you fix the above, you should be able to navigate to `ClubDetail` and see a list of club members.

Comment: point1 : I get the following error - `Field name `person_set` is not valid for model `Club``

Comment: This line `clubs = models.ManyToManyField(Club)` creates a related name of `person_set` automatically. You really should have this field available using the code you posted above.

Comment: Also, point3: gives me single person details with details about multiple clubs he is in whereas I wanted clubdetails with various persons. And on clicking on one out of those persons, persondetails based on the view.

Comment: You've written `ClubDetail` as a `ListCreateAPIView` that returns a list of `Person` filtered by club. If I implement your code (with the changes in 3 & 4) I get a list as described. If this is not what you want you may need to rethink this view.

Comment: See what I wanted was 3 api's `/clubs` `/club/<pk>/details/` and `/persons/<pk> - persons in a particular club` . Could you please explain what changes I need to make to achieve this. Thanks for explaining and answering so many questions. Been at it for hours.

Comment: So I get you want `ClubList` to list clubs, `PersonDetail` to represent a single person, but what exactly do you want out of `ClubDetail`? Should it be a list of persons in a club, or should it be the club information, with a list of persons nested in the response?

Comment: Exactly.it should be a list of people in the club.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a many to many relationship, make sure to explicitly declare the field, like so:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    
    parts__part = serializers.CharField()
    

    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = ['date', 'url', 'type','parts__part']
```